# Set Mouse Cursor in Multithreading Application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've got a C# Application where I work some things in an workerthread.
Before I start the workerthread I try to Change the Mouse Cursor in the Button Click Event in the Mainthread.
Now I wonder why the Cursor doesn't change.

```
    private void barButtonItemBulkImport_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
      Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;        
      PxDAL pdal = new PxDAL();
      pdal.ReactivateAdressMutation += new PxDAL.Del_ReactivateAdressMutation(ReactivateAdressMutation);

      pdal.StartContact();
    }

    private void ReactivateAdressMutation()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new AdressMutation.Del_BatchImportFinished(ReactivateAdressMutation), new Object[] { });
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try

```
this.cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

and

```
this.cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Respectively